# Can I observe when a UIViewController change UIViewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, nsnotificationcenter

I need to make an observer which will call whenever the UIViewcontroller is changed
How to make it in delegate or a single method to observe complete hierarchy changes in UIViewcontroller changes?

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self // put here the view controller which has to be notified
                                         selector:@selector(viewcontrollerChanged:)
                                             name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" 
                                           object:nil];
```

Comment: Normally any changes in the UI are registered with the call of `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews` these functions get called with each changes you do in UI of UIViewController.

Comment: not to want to put code in each class....is there any way to check in a single method like in delegate of app ? 
I need to place a banner at the bottom of each UIViewcontroller so need to reframe it , i have written a separate class and add it as subview at the topmostviewcontroller, My Viewcontroller hierarchy have tabbar and Navigation push view with tab bar hidden. So i need to adjust that banner according to it...

Comment: You can create a BaseViewController class and define a delegate property in it, inherit with each UIViewController you want to apply changes from, it can be easily handled in the Super class this way.

Comment: @iphonic thanks for suggestion,..any tutorial or link of it?